# Only first emitted value by StateFlow is being reflected in Compose UI

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, compose-desktop

I am working with Compose Desktop. I have created a ViewModel class that is emitting some states as follows

```kotlin
    internal class ImportViewModel(private val dbHelper: FirestoreHelper) {
    private val scope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default)

    private val uiState = MutableStateFlow<ImportUiState>(InitialState)
    fun uiState() = uiState as StateFlow<ImportUiState>

    fun beginImport(filePath: String) {
        scope.launch {
            try {
                update("Before Delay")
                delay(100)
                update("Delay 1")
                delay(100)
                update("Delay 2")
                delay(100)
                update("Delay 3")
                delay(100)
                update("Delay 4")
                delay(100)
                update("Delay 5")
            } catch (exception: Exception) {
                println(exception.stackTrace)
                update(exception.localizedMessage)
            }
```

Where `update` method is defined as follows

```kotlin
private fun update(text: String) {
        println(text)
        scope.launch {
            uiState.emit(ProgressState(text))
        }
    }
```

I am collecting this `StateFlow` in my composable as follows

```kotlin
@Composable
fun ImportTab() {
    var progressText by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
    val viewModel = ImportViewModel(FirestoreHelper)
    val uiState = viewModel.uiState().collectAsState().value

    Column(modifier = Modifier.padding(24.dp)) {
        Button(onClick = {
            viewModel.beginImport("")
        }) {
            Text("Begin Import")
        }

        if (uiState is ProgressState) {
            progressText = uiState.status
        }

        if (progressText.isNotEmpty()) {
            Text(text = progressText)
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is in UI I cannot get `progressText` to get reflected after the first emission. I can see proper text in the console. I have tried playing around with `Dispatchers` and working with `uiState.status` directly instead of `progressText` but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Problem seems to be this line

```kotlin
     val viewModel = ImportViewModel(FirestoreHelper)
```

`ViewModel` probably being is recreated on every recomposition. Injecting it in the `Composable` method fixes the problem for me.

```kotlin
@Composable
internal fun ImportTab(viewModel: ImportViewModel) {
..
}
```

Still not sure the best way to inject such dependencies in a `Composable` method though.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Android, you can use view models as showed in [documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state#viewmodels-source-of-truth).

In Compose for Desktop these are not available at the moment.

To save a view model between recomposition, you can use `remember`. As far as I know Desktop doesn't have configuration changes like Android rotations, so `remember` value should live until the view is in the view tree.

```
val viewModel = remember { ImportViewModel(FirestoreHelper) }
```

Comment: I am using compose-desktop at the moment. I will try this and let you know. Thanks!